# Python: How to change variable in http post request

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, post, https

```
data = {'Email':'myemail@gmail.com','Name':'1','Password':'gfgf65jh56456jh67'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Hello,
I am using above code to send http request and it worked well. However, I want to use for loop to change "Name" variable. So, this is my code after changing

```
for i in range(1,1000): 
    data = "{'Email':'myemail@gmail.com','Name':'" + str(i) + "','Password':'gfgf65jh56456jh67'}"
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

However, I got an output from server: {'Message': 'An error has occurred.'}. It is not python error. So, how to fix my code ? Thank you :)

Comment: 1. Provide the error, we can't guess it. 2. Why do you think the error has anything to do with you changing the `name` value? 3. `data` is already a dict. No need to bother with changing it to a string, while you can simply do `data['name'] = str(i)`.

Comment: I got the error from server, not python. The error is : {'Message': 'An error has occurred.'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line that changes data, `data` is not a dictionary any more but a string...

Change data simply by:

```
data['Name'] = str(i)
```